# How to show drop down Angularjs-ui-select onclick on hyperlink tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I want to bind ui-select to `<a></a>` tag, so when we click on this tag, it show ui-select.

Please see the following demo [Plunker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rqpqKtcwVxX7vKJutYKZ?p=preview)

In demo, select-ui are shown separately, but I want to **show it only when I click on following drop-downs  (person, country)**, when I click on person It show the following ui-select. Similarly When I click on country it should show the ui-select for country.

**It should be attach with the drop-down,**

```
<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

I modified the my [pluncker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rqpqKtcwVxX7vKJutYKZ?p=preview) as suggested by **Naga Sandeep**, **but after selection of country, I am not able to select again person.**

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is
1) toggle a property on `scope`
2) `ng-show` that property on `ui-select`.

```
<a href="" ng-click="toggleCountry()">Click for countries</a>

<ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;" ng-show="showCountry">
```

In your js file toggle the property

```
$scope.showCountry = false;

$scope.toggleCountry = function()
{
    $scope.showCountry = !$scope.showCountry;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it will not attach with the corresponding hyperlink, I want to attach ui-select with hyperlink..

Comment: Have you tried my code? What exactly is not working. Can you show a plunker after adding my code?

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Plz see the link, http://plnkr.co/edit/rqpqKtcwVxX7vKJutYKZ?p=preview but after selection of country, I am not able to select person again..

Answer (score 0):

i updated the plunker example : http://plnkr.co/edit/e64JGEakaKRVBgNwgpDg?p=preview

### into controller, add isActive() function:

```
//that function checks if the ui-select is active
 $scope.isActive = function(type){
    return $scope.selectedType == type;
  };
```

into HTML:

Just wrap your ui-select into `<div></div>` and check if they are active, like this :

```
<div ng-show="isActive('person')">
    <h3>Select2 theme</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{person.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      <small>
        email: {{person.email}}
        age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>  
  </div>


<div ng-show="isActive('country')">
  <h3>Selectize theme</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{country.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

Hope helps , good luck.